# Python. Index through a list by random set size specified in another list

Tags: python, indexing, psychopy

I want to loop through a list of words in different set sizes, and the order of the set size is specified in another list. I want to jump to the new word in the word list after each trial set.
For example, I have

`stimuli_words = ["tree","bird","cake","ocean","dance","statistics","headphone", "red","duck"]`

and I have `set_size = [2, 4, 3]`

I use `chosen_size = +1` to loop through the set_size list. I want the first trial to show "tree","bird", second trial to show "cake","ocean","dance","statistics", and third trial to show "headphone", "red","duck", how should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a helper function would be appropriate:

```
def chunks_with_sizes(li, sizes):
    i = 0
    for sz in sizes:
        yield li[i:i+sz]
        i += sz
```

Then:

```
>>> list(chunks_with_sizes(stimuli_words, set_size))
[['tree', 'bird'], ['cake', 'ocean', 'dance', 'statistics'], ['headphone', 'red', 'duck']]
```